# DataGridView show Int instead of Double values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm using an SqlServerCe database and a dataset. There's no problem to transfer data to database. There Are two double value columns in the database displaying values properly. When I fill DataGridview from database with these values, the double values apperaring as Int. Here's the part of code if necessary.

```
if (rdb_FillData.Checked)
        {
            dbDataSet.AppDataDataTable dTable = new App1.dbDataSet.AppDataDataTable();
            AppDataTableAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            AppDataBindingSource.DataSource = dTable;
            AppDataDataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

Comment: can you check whether dTable has decimal values or not.

Comment: I think the problem is dTable. I was changed table format a bit. Now when I check datatypes it shows me int instead of double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the DataType after the Datatable is filled with data. However, you can clone the Data table, change the column type and load data from previous data table to the cloned table as shown below.

Sample code to  change datatype of a column to Decimal

```
DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Decimal);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
{
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your values in dTable, if they are true it's possible you have created your columns manually and column types are wrong.
if dTable values are wrong maybe your AppDataDataTable column types are wrong.